# Quiero hacer refresh del token de autenticación, pero mis promesas (fetch) no se ejecuta de forma encadenada

Tags: javascript, fetch, promesas

Me estoy conectando a una API que requiere autenticación JWT, esto lo hago usando FETCH para hacer las peticiones desde JS.

El token access de JWT tiene un tiempo de expiración, por lo cual cuado dejo pasar el 5 minutos y ejecuto mi codigo en el evento onclick (botón), la petición es rechazada por la API informando que la credencial (token access) no es valida. Pero al presionar por segunda vez el botón la petición se ejecuta sin problemas.

Lo que entiendo es que se ejecuta el `refresh()` pero la respuesta de esa petición llega después de que se ejecuta `cargaMasivaPersonal()` y no se alcanza a actualizar el token.

A continuación mis archivos

login.js

```
function refresh() {
    var refresh = localStorage.getItem('refresh');
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

    var raw = JSON.stringify({
        "refresh": refresh
    });

    var requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: myHeaders,
        body: raw,
        redirect: 'follow'
    };
    

    return fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/refresh/", requestOptions)
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(result => {
        if (result.access) {
            localStorage.setItem('access', result.access);
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('error', error)
    });
}
```

personal.js

```
function promesaCargaMasivaPersonal() {
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    token = localStorage.getItem('access');
    myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("archivo", document.getElementById('archivo').files[0]);

    var requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: myHeaders,
    body: formdata,
    redirect: 'follow'
    };

    return fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/clinical_record/personal/carga_masiva/", requestOptions)
    
}

function cargarMasivaPersonal() {

    refresh()
    .then(() => promesaCargaMasivaPersonal())
    .then(response => {
        if (response.status == 200) {
            $('#modal_carga_masiva').modal('hide');
            listar();
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Cargado!',
                text: 'Personal cargado con éxito.',
                icon: 'success',
                confirmButtonText: 'Cerrar'
            })
        }
        document.querySelector('.loader').style.display = 'block';
        return response.json()
    })
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('error', error)
    })
    .finally(() => {
        document.querySelector('.loader').style.display = 'none';
    });
}
```

Estoy incursionando en el fronend, desconosco que estoy haciendo mal. Agradezco la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo muy bien lo que planteas, pero puedo ver que estas intentando usar una API atraves de fetch, replantea tu metodo de forma asincrona, ejemplo:

```
    async function conectar(){
    const parametros = {
    ...tusparametros
    };  
    const consulta = await fetch("url", parametros);
    const respuestas = await consulta.json()
    return respuestas    
    }
```

Comment: Hice una actualización de la pregunta, creo que ahora es mas especifica. Gracias por tu aporte.